# Including HTML <meta> element conditionally

Tags: html

Firstly, I've done some Google'ing and found the IE 'conditional comment' and understand it's non-standard. I also get the impression there is no standard HTML 'IF' so my question is about what I need to do to achieve the same effect (Javascript perhaps?)...

I'd like to conditionally include an external .html file (from a selection of external .html files). Specifically, the external files each contains nothing but a `<meta>` element on a single line. Alternatively is it possible to have multiple inline `<meta>` elements in a HTML file and to 'choose' one conditionally (effectively ignoring the others)?

Basically, can I do something that would achieve the same as one of either of these pseudo code examples?

Example using pseudo code for external files...

```
<html>
    <head>
        if some-condition
            <!--#include file="meta1.html" -->
        else
            <!--#include file="meta2.html" -->
        ...
    </head>
     ...
</html>
```

Alternative example (again pseudo code) for selecting alternative  elements directly...

```
<html>
    <head>
        if some-condition
            <meta name="viewport" content="abc" />
        else
            <meta name="viewport" content="def" />
        ...
    </head>
     ...
</html>
```

NOTE: In all cases the `<meta name` attribute will always be `viewport` - it's just the `content` attribute which needs changing perhaps with some other attributes.

**EDIT:** The main condition would be the type of client. One example is that to help correctly size web app pages on an Android device you can use certain `content` data for the `viewport` that only Android devices understand. For conventional browsers, I would set a default set of data for `content` (for width/height for example). This could also be expanded for other clients such as Google TV, iOS etc etc.

Comment: What would the conditions be?

Comment: If you're ready for conditional HTML, then you're ready for a server-side language. I'd suggest starting simple, such as with PHP.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I had thought PHP might be required - the problem is that part of the server-side is out of my hands. I'm a rookie when it comes to most things web-related and just spent the past week learning a ton about html/javascript/jquery that I didn't know before....still a rookie though. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using Javascript:

```
document.head.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<meta name="viewport" content="abc" />' );
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/ccX5p/

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with javascript / jQuery quite easily.

Set your conditions and then `append()` to the `head`.

Example:

```
if(//condition here){
    $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="abc" />')
}

else{
    $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="def" />')
}
```

Comment: Where would the javascript/jquery code go? (See my rookie comment on my answer :) ). It's not clear to me at which stage the `<meta>` element is parsed by the client in relation to everything else.

Comment: Thanks. I've upvoted but ThinkingStiff's answer pointed me at `window.onload` (yes, I'm really that much of a novice when it comes to HTML)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a server side, like asp or java, the thing becomes lot easier for you.

i shall consider you are not using server side coding.

use javascript for getting the browser name (navigator.appname I guess).

then you may use DOM to add `<meta ..../>` tags inside `<head>` element.

document.getElementsByTagNam('Head').appendChild(metaChild);